# Java : threads are limited to 25% of the CPU

Tags: java, multithreading

when i use threads or the main thread, i noticed that they are limited to 25% of the CPU for each thread.

Is there a way to tell a thread to use more CPU ? because i find it a bit limitative that way.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean each of your CPUs is only used at 25% capacity? Or your overall CPU capacity is only used at 25% (and if you have 4 CPUs, that means one of them is probably 100% busy)?

Comment: which tool did you use to measure CPU consumption? On what operating system? Linux shows 100%  when one processor is fully loaded and Windows - when all.

Comment: A thread would only use the amount of computation power required. you cannot tell it to take more power unnecessarily. Check out my answer for really giving CPU a good heavy load.

Answer (score 8):

You probably have a quad core machine. You can't have a thread run on more than one core.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Mainn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int noOfProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        System.out.println(noOfProcessors);
        for (int i = 0; i< noOfProcessors ; i++){
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(;;){
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

This would use  a lot of CPU test it.

*A thread or process would only use the amount of computation power required. you cannot tell it to take more computation power unless you create a code that requires more computation*

**One thread in JAVA can run on single core at a time. So all I have done is create a thread for each core.**

Comment: that's what I have said in my answer